# how to create the Organisation level user policy in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My requirement is I need to automatically disable the user which is not login to GCP for more than 100days. how do I create the policy? I have more than 50 projects in my org and It should apply to every project.

How can I generate the user's last login report?

thanks in advance

Comment: Google Cloud does not record last login. Google Workplace does. What are you using for your identity system (Google Accounts, Workplace, Identity Platorm)? You will need to review their documentation.

Comment: This might help if you want to catch inactivity at workspace level: https://xfanatical.com/blog/automatically-suspend-inactive-users-in-g-suite/